# Update ICU Version in PHP 5.3.6

Tags: php, mediawiki, icu, intl

I'm spend some time to install MediaWiki. As install base i use my virtual machine with windows 2003 and iis. After installing php and configuring some things i stuck right now at configuring intl and icu.

After a while i recognize, intl is a standard extension delivered in the win installer of php. Unfortunately, they use icu 3.8 and MediaWiki recommanded to use a newer version.

Because i quite new in MediaWiki i try to install all recommandations.

i found the new icu*.dll in the web [downloadlink](http://site.icu-project.org/download/48) but not the intl.dll. Copying the 7 files icu*48.dll in the directory where the "old" icu*38.dll files placed won't work. I understand why this is so because i suppose, the dll needs the file names.

So the question is, where can i get a newer version of intl.dll with newer version of icu or can i compile a intl.dll with icu 4.6. By the way, I'm not a compiling crack.

Thank you verry much
Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the default settings at compile time, you can't replace icu 3.8 with icu 4.8. They are designed to coexist and not conflict. You'll need to recompile intl.dll.